# JHtml::_('jquery.framework') No Conflict Mode

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, custom-component

I'm writing an add-in, and I need to use JQuery.

Are there any ramifications to using JHtml::('jquery.framework') in No Conflict mode so that JQuery is accessed via the jQuery namespace (rather than $)?

I'd really prefer to use it like that anyhow. I just want to make sure that it's not a norm. I've "read" that MooTools is kind of the default and is set to "$".

Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's already loaded in no conflict mode

> In order to load jQuery, use JHtml::_('jquery.framework');
>
> This will load the jQuery version 1.11.3 library in no conflict mode.
>   This means it is accessed via the jQuery namespace, not through $.
>
> To load it in normal mode, call JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);

You can have more specific information about loading frameworks in Joomla [at this page](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Javascript_Frameworks)

When writing your jQuery, you can use `$` an an alias of the `jQuery` global scope, like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var something = $('.something');
});
```

Comment: I was reading the referenced page on loading frameworks, but it does not state that the JQuery Framework is included in no conflict mode by default.

Comment: and, in the interests of completeness, unless you call JHtml::_(), then your scripts will be loaded before JQuery, and you'll have dependency problems. So, the moral is you have to load the framework yourself if you depend on it.

Comment: I think jQuery is included by default in no-conflict mode on joomla 3.x and higher versions. A new joomla installation with custom template loads itself **jquery.min.js** and **jquery-noconflict.js** from media folder without using JHtml statements.

Comment: @GeorgeSexton Are you saying that any JS frameworks built into Joomla and loaded by default or through JHtml::_() will be loaded _after_ all scripts that are loaded manually (through <script> tag, for example)?